# Does txt file not support hyperlink to jump to a specific page like pdf?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, hyperlink

I want to make table of contents in txt file each line of which contains hyperlink to jump right to the desired contents for easier navigation, like pdf bookmark

Is this viable option for txt file in plain text mode?

Comment: No. Plain text files do not support bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, **NO**. It does not work with plain text files.

You can do it with text files using Markdown syntax. You'll need headlines, inline link syntax and a MarkdownViewer as a plug-in with Notepad++.

```markdown
# Contents

[inline link](#Visual-Studio)

[Home](https://www.help-info.de/)

[Is the Help helpful?](https://www.help-info.de/files/ebook_is-the-help-helpful.pdf)
```

[image]

---

### This part is not about your question:

But it may be interesting for you. **Ignore** if you don't want to create ebooks. Please note, using Markdown is a single-sourcing way. But it has a learn curve.

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/epub.html) can produce output from Markdown (.md) text files in the EPUB electronic book format. EPUB books can be viewed on iPads and other electronic book readers, including many smart phones. usinf PowerShell the command is like this:

```
PS D:\_working> pandoc ebook.md -o ebook.epub
```

[Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) is a small, lightweight reading application. Sumatra PDF works with EPUB format. Sumatra can even be used in “portable” mode, so you can place it on a USB drive or in a cloud storage folder and run it on computers without installing it first.

Sample from Pandoc link above opened with Sumatra PDF:

[image]

Comment: The nice thing about Markdown is that it's reasonably easy to read (and understand) even if you don't have a Markdown viewer. The downside is that Windows doesn't render it natively.

Comment: thanks for the workaround. I will definitely give it a try but since most of my txt files are for reading ebook and not programming, wonder if it won't get too complicated and disturb the reading with list of commands.

Comment: @takfa - you're welcome. See my edit. But, Markdown inline links, yes may be too complicated for your (unknown) needs ...